# Problems with dowloading and installing programmatically apk android 10 11

Tags: java, android

I'm having a problem downloading and installing the app.
On android below 10 this code works.
I am trying to update my application from the server.

**Manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
...


<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
```

**Activity**
If there is an update, then a snackbar appears and by clicking update the application should download and install

```
 private void showSnackbar() {
        Snackbar snackbar =
                Snackbar.make(
                        findViewById(android.R.id.content),
                        "update available",
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
        snackbar.setAction("update", new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {                 
                try {
                    if (checkPermission()) {
                        UpdateApp atualizaApp = new UpdateApp();
                        atualizaApp.setContext(CommonListObjects.this);
                        atualizaApp.execute("http://195.200.000.000:0000/app.apk");
                    } else {
                        requestPermission();
                    }                     
                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {  
                   
                }
            }
        });
        snackbar.show();
    }

 @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0) {

                boolean locationAccepted = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                boolean cameraAccepted = grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                if (locationAccepted && cameraAccepted) {
                    UpdateApp updateApp = new UpdateApp();
                    updateApp.setContext(CommonListObjects.this);
                    updateApp.execute("http://195.200.000.000:0000/app.apk");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    private boolean checkPermission() {
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        int result1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

        return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && result1 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    private void requestPermission() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
```

**this is how it loads**

```
 @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            try {    
                URL url = new URL(arg0[0]);
                HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                c.setRequestMethod("GET");
                c.setDoOutput(true);
                c.connect();
                int lenghtOfFile = c.getContentLength();
                String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "app.apk";
                File file = new File(PATH);
                boolean isCreate = file.mkdirs();
                File outputFile = new File(file, "app.apk");
                if (outputFile.exists()) {
                    boolean isDelete = outputFile.delete();
                }
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

                InputStream is = c.getInputStream();

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int len1;
                long total = 0;
                while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    total += len1;
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
                    publishProgress((int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));
                }
                fos.close();
                is.close();
                if (mPDialog != null)
                    mPDialog.dismiss();
                installApk();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("UpdateAPP", "Update error! " + e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }
```

**this is how the installation works**

```
   void installApk(){

            String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "app.apk"+ "/" + "app.apk";
            File file = new File(PATH);
            if(file.exists()) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(uriFromFile(getApplicationContext(), new File(PATH)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                try {
                    getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error in opening the file!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"installing",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        Uri uriFromFile(Context context, File file) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                return FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);
            } else {
                return Uri.fromFile(file);
            }
        }
```

on android below 10 works, but in 10 and 11 does not work. even the file does not load.

Comment: Indeed as you cannot create files on root of external storage anymore. Download to getExternalFilesDir() instead. No permissions needed.

Comment: `boolean isCreate = file.mkdirs();` Only call mkdirs if the directory does not exist yet. So use file.exists() to check. If mkdirs fails then stop. You better care for a directory before you start your asynctask.

Comment: @blackapps if you talk about it `String PATH = Objects.requireNonNull(mContext.getExternalFilesDir(null)).getAbsolutePath();` then this method does not work either

Comment: There is no reason that you cannot download to that path. There is no reason that you cannot install from that path. And you did not tell what does not work.